# How to invoke [BUG] Segmentation fault or another bug in Ruby for testing reasons?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I want to test Sidekiq PRO reliability on local machine so I need to somehow trigger bug like `[BUG] Segmentation fault` manually to kill Sidekiq process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just kill the Sidekiq process: `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a segmentation fault by sending `SIGSEGV` to self. This will trigger the bug handler.

```
Process.kill("SEGV", Process.pid)
```